# Execute windows cmd prompt command through c# code.

Tags: c#, cmd, process, command

I want to execute any sample command of cmd.exe through c# code. Eg. Time/ver this command i want to execute through c# code. 
1. By opening cmd.exe and execute.
2. by hiding cmd.exe and get the cmd response in the code.

In this both cases i want to execute. Can you please suggest me correct code links. I have been trying various codes of Process() class but not working for me.

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: What issue are you having with the Process() class?

Comment: @vipersassassin Thanks for reply. Issue has been resolved in few tries.

Closing off.